# How do I save two times in one request using webflux and r2dbc?

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

I use webflux with r2dbc.
I try to save in two tables in one service, but there is only one actual save.
There may be a way to do flatmap twice in the handler, but I want to use transaction in service.

```
Handler.java
Mono<ServerResponse> save(ServerRequest request) {
        return request.bodyToMono(Todo.class)
            .flatMap(todo-> todoService.save(todo))
            .flatMap(todo -> ok().build());
    }
```

```
TodoService.java
public Mono<Todo> save(Todo todo) { 
    todoLogRepository.save(getTodoLog(todo)); // this now work
    return todoRepository.save(todo);
}
```

```
Router.java
@Bean
public RouterFunction<?> routes(InvestmentHandler handler) {
    return route(POST("/save"), handler::save);
}
```

Comment: Use `zip` to create one Mono out of two.

Comment: `return todoLogRepository.save(getTodoLog(todo)).then(todoRepository.save(todo));`